# Unable to find Effects in Adobe Premier Pro

Tags: adobe-premiere

Trying to add the effects option so I can add a transition effects to my video clip. I went to windown and see that effects is checked but it does not appear on the lower left hand side. How can I add the options to the lower left hand side? I see the Media Browser in the menu but no Effects. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It could be anywhere and it could be collapsed. Try hiding it and showing it again and if that doesn't help yet, toggle it like 5 times to see what changes in the UI. If that fails, you may be able to find it easier by resetting to one of the default workspaces.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Video editing is [off-topic here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Sorry about that. Might be better to flag your own question and ask a mod to migrate it to Video Production Stack Exchange instead.